# Are JDBC select queries through a single connection less efficient that a proc containing those queries?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

If I open a single JDBC connection (for Oracle), and execute multiple `select` queries, will it be less efficient than calling a procedure that executes those queries, and returns the result in cursors?

Edit: Sample queries are:

```
select id, name from animals;
select * from animal_reservoir where animal_id=id;
```

(The actual first query would be quite complicated, and the id returned would be used as an input multiple times in the second query. As such, the first query will be inefficient to use as subquery in the second query. Also, the queries can't be combined.)

Comment: What are these selects, and how would you even use a single cursor here?

Comment: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf doesn't say anything specific on the said matter. But in Chapter 14 it says "The batch update facility allows multiple SQL statements to be submitted to a data
source for processing at once. Submitting multiple SQL statements, instead of
individually, can greatly improve performance." So I presume that it would be better to execute it by proc (or batch as it say) rather than multiple single queries...

Comment: Why not combine it to 1 SQL query? it looks possible

Comment: Updated the question. @Ketan I want to execute multiple select queries, not update queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main differences are

- fewer roundtrips (important if there are many small queries, otherwise not so much)
- no need to send "intermediate" results (that are only needed for the next query, but not in the end) back to the client

How much of an impact this has completely depends on the application.

And often, there may be other alternatives (such as issuing different kind of queries in the first place; someone mentioned a JOIN in the comments -- or caching -- or indexing -- or data denormalization -- or ...
) to consider as well.

As usual, do what feels most natural first and optimize when you find there is an issue.

Comment: Since I'm reusing the same connection, calling multiple select queries should have the same impact as calling those same queries inside a procedure which is called just once, right?

Comment: If you call three queries it goes to the server and back three times. If you call one (server-side) stored procedure, it only does a single round-trip (unless the results need to be paged). If your application does not need the result from the first two queries (but only the result from the third one), then the procedure only needs to return the third result (and the first two do not leave the database server).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided SQL queries that must use procedure

You can do 1 SQL query with multiple "inner SQL" using `with` clause for example:

```
with animals as (
select id, name from animals
)
select * from animal_reservoir,animals where animal_id=animals.id;
```